# Why does Google Play Games keep auto-updating, even though I have disabled auto-updates?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, application-autoupdate, motorola-moto-e, google-play-games

Ever since the Lollipop update for my Moto E, storage space on the phone has been very tight. To make the phone more usable for the things I use it for, I've uninstalled the updates for all of the system apps I don't use. And of course, because now I have to keep a close eye on what gets installed, I've disabled auto-updates entirely in my Google Play Store settings.

Unfortunately, for some reason the Google Play Games app continues to update automatically. This is the only app for which it happens. All of the other system apps remain un-updated, and of course for the apps I do use, I have to manually update them when an update is available, just as expected.

I checked the settings for the Google Play Games app and did not see anything there that would affect auto-updating.

Why is the Google Play Games app continuing to update itself automatically, even though I have configured the Google Play Store to not do any automatic updates? How can I prevent this from happening, so that I can uninstall the updates for Google Play Games and have them *stay* uninstalled?

Note: I am looking for a solution that works on a stock, not-rooted phone.

Comment: Do you use Google Play Games? If not, why not just disable the app? That shouldn't be causing auto update of Play Games though I'm yet to fully test this.

Comment: @Firelord: ah, I did not realize that disabling an app would also prevent the update. I will try that. It would still be nice to know why the app was auto-updating, even though I have no auto-updates enabled. But at least it will be good if there's a work-around.

Comment: There's no proof or reference, but based on my experience, I think Google Play Service forced update Play Games (just like how it updated Play Store app) because of the framework update on Play Games (previously, it's using Google+ info, but now it's independent). This is only my wild guess though.

Comment: I haven't noticed Google Play Games auto-updated, but Google Play Services, Google Play store, Google Play Services for Instant apps are all forced updates.